# Classic Christmas postcard with two columns?

Tags: graphics, two-column

I am rather new with TeX. I would like to produce a classic Christmas postcard for new year best wishes.

I would like to have 2 cols. Left side the picture and right side the text, maybe with a nice font. It is very hard to make.

herewith the current achievement. Would you please give me hints how to progress further?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol} \usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
[
I wish you a happy new year 2018 !
]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

A compilation with widely available pdflatex would be desired.

Herewith a like-classic example in the picture of aim.

[image]

Comment: If you want to use "exotic" fonts I would suggest using xelatex.

Comment: i wrote pdflatex above

Answer (score 1):

You might use `minipage`. For different font types, see [this page](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/venturisadfold/). E.g. I used the Venturis ADF old font type (`\usepackage{venturisold}` is needed for this). You might play with the widths and alignments.

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{venturisold}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
I wish you a happy new year 2018 !
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have added venturisold.sty into the directory, but  pdflatex tells that it does not work during font making. It still shows up with times. Is minipage package available by default on all tex installations, with pdflatex?

Comment: `Minipage` is available. First try it without `venturisold`, and then you can install the other package, too.

Comment: which DLL shall be installed on BSD?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familiar with BSD, you need someone else's help